# elasticsearch: how do I groupby a field and avg up totals?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I define a schema like:

```
"mappings": {
    "sales": {
        "properties": {
            "gender": { "type": "byte" },
            "age":    { "type": "byte" },
            "amount": { "type": "integer" },
            "dow":    { "type": "byte" },
            "day_of": { "type": "date" },
        }
    }
}
```

And add 1000's of sales documents to ES with data like 0 for male, 1 for female, dow is 1 for monday, 2 for tues, etc.

How do I get a results like:

```
gender 0: average amount of sales
gender 1: average amount of sales
```

or

```
dow monday: average amount of sales
dow tues: average amount of sales
dow wed: average amount of sales
dow thurs: average amount of sales
dow friday: average amount of sales
```

and

```
dow monday AND age 18-24: average amount of sales
dow tues AND age 18-24 AND female: average amount of sales
dow wed AND age 18-24: average amount of sales
dow thurs AND age 18-24: average amount of sales
dow friday AND age 18-24: average amount of sales
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each one of these is pretty straight forward, but you're really asking a few different questions.

There's no need to explicitly call out each value as you have done (though there's nothing technically wrong with it). Instead, you can ask "simpler" questions and allow the query scope to control what you even see.

> gender 0: average amount of sales
>   gender 1: average amount of sales

This can become a simpler question:

> gender N: average amount of sales

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_gender": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "gender"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_sales": {
          "avg" :{
            "field": "amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> dow monday: average amount of sales
>   dow tues: average amount of sales
>   dow wed: average amount of sales
>   dow thurs: average amount of sales
>   dow friday: average amount of sales

This can become a simpler question:

> dow N, *except Saturday or Sunday*: average amount of sales

Assuming `dow == 0` is Sunday and `dow == 6` is Saturday:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "dow": [0, 6]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_dow": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "dow",
        "size": 5
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_sales": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, the last one simply adds another filter to that question:

> AND age 18-24 AND female

I assume the `AND female` was meant to copied for all of them because that is how you answered it:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "dow": [0, 6]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "gender": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "age": {
              "gte": 18,
              "lte": 24
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_dow": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "dow",
        "size": 5
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_sales": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You already discovered the `stats` aggregation, but you're only asking for the average, so using the more specific `avg` aggregation will not waste time performing calculations that you don't care about.

You will also want to read about the differences between the [query context and the filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html) to understand why I used `filter` above instead of `must` (basically, filters can be cached *and* they do not score; they only answer "yes or no" questions, which is what you want here).

Comment: thanks! this is great! This is what I'm making BTW http://i.imgur.com/1C0Klb8.png

Comment: Neat. Be sure that you're not reimplementing Kibana unnecessarily!

Comment: oh wow thank u pickypg I just installed Kibana and it's amazing. This is a great SO experience. I wonder why my original question got a down vote. I felt a RTFM feel from that down vote but I did (read the manual) and still had a question. I think this is just how SO should work. Reveal yourself downvoter and explain! :)

Answer (score 0):

i think this works:

```
  "query": {
        "bool": {          
            "must": [
                { "match": {"gender":1} },
                { "range": {"age": {"gte": 18, "lte": 24}} }
            ]
        }
    },
"size": 0,
"aggs":{"monday" :{"filter":{"term":{"dow":1}}, "aggs":{"s":{"stats":{"field": "amount"}}}},
        "tuesday":{"filter":{"term":{"dow":2}}, "aggs":{"s":{"stats":{"field": "amount"}}}}}
```